# having each line numbered in an align environment with brackets

Tags: align, numbering, arrays, eqnarray

I'm trying to get what looks like the following, but with number at every lines.

```
\begin{align}
\text{Minimize}  \quad & f(x) \\
\text{subject to}\quad & \text{for $i = 1,\cdots,N$:} \\
                       & \left\lfloor
                         \begin{array}{l}
                         u_{i} \leq 0 \\
                         v_{i} \leq 0 \\
                         w_{i} \leq 0 \\
                         \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: It's quite impossible that the code you show produces that output. You should have a spurious `l` after the `array`.

Comment: That was a mistake when I tried uploading the image.
I corrected it now.